# Data modelling for graph search

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have user node and within user node I have some properties like UserName, EMail, Gender, Birthday, City, State & Country. If I want give graph search like facebook, How should I have to create node? Should I have to create different node for city, state, country or set as an property? and what about birthday and gender?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*if it is like Facebook graph search where you have millions of user nodes then you should go with storing individual property of user in user node.

*If your searching will be only user centric then creating individual node for only users will be good option

*If you don't have millions of users and if you'll be having frequent search queries like give me users of this country, give me users of this state then creating seperate nodes for city, country will be good option.

*As far as birthday and gender goes, I think it'd be better to store it in user node only.